# Obtaining the error reason from an Angular subscribe

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I have an Angular subscribe that capturing the response from an API:

```
.subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { registered: true }});
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error => {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.loading = false;

                });
```

However, my server is returning error reasons in the body as such:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "reason": "The Account was not found."
}
```

How would I capture the error "reason" to be able to return it to the frontend?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check for the error with the tap operator and throw:

```
source.pipe(
  tap(x => {
    if(x.error){
      throw new Error(x.reason);
    }
  })
).subscribe(
data => {
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { registered: true }});
    console.log(data);
},
error => {
    this.error = error.message;
    this.loading = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
.subscribe(
   (data: any) => {
        if (data.error) {
            this.error = data;
            this.loading = false;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { registered: true } });
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
);
```